Playwright C# .NET - IntersectionObserver, Google Analytics & ScrollIntoViewIfNeededAsync does not fully scroll in mobile viewport
So, I've got a very interesting issue when it comes to some Playwright tests.
I am trying to automate a Google Analytics event that gets triggered based on the IntersectionObserver in my company's website; so to automate this in Playwright with C# .NET; I decided to use the ScrollIntoViewIfNeededAsync() command to try and tell the Playwright to scroll to make the full element is in view.
I then retrieve the dataLayer from the window to see if the Google Analytics event has occurred.
When I try and run the Playwright test Category_Page_Should_Have_All_Heroes; I expect the page to open in a mobile viewport and, when on the page, scroll the element into view and assert that the Google Analytics event is being triggered; but it is not showing the event as expected.
When I set a breakpoint and try it manually, I confirm that the event is not triggered, but, if I make 1 mouse scroll wheel interaction and scroll down by 1 notch, then the event is triggered, which indicates to me that the ScrollIntoViewIfNeededAsync() is not fully scrolling the full Intersection into view so that the event gets triggered.
Does anyone know if this is something I need to raise with Playwright themselves or is there something I can fix myself?
Code:
public class DataLayerModel {
  public GAEvent? Event { get; set; }
}

public class GAEvent {
  public string? name { get; set; }
  public string? creativeName { get; set; }
  public string? creativeSlot { get; set; }
  public string? itemBrand { get; set; }
  public string? itemName { get; set; }
  public string? itemVariant { get; set; }
  public string? itemListName { get; set; }
  public string? itemListLength { get; set; }
  public int? promotionId { get; set; }
  public int? locationId { get; set; }
  public string? itemId { get; set; }
  public int? index { get; set; }
  public string? pdCashbackRate { get; set; }
  public string? pdOfferEndDate { get; set; }
}

public async Task HasSuperHero(DeviceType deviceType) {
  if (_page != null) {
    await _page.IsVisibleAsync(_singleHeroSelector);
    await _page.Locator(_singleHeroSelector).First.ScrollIntoViewIfNeededAsync();
    await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(1000);
    await retrieveDataLayer();
    await validateDataLayer("viewSingleHero");
  }
}

public async Task retrieveDataLayer() {
  if (_page == null) {
    throw new Exception("Page is null");
  }

  await _page.WaitForTimeoutAsync(2000);
  _dataLayer = await _page.EvaluateAsync<DataLayerModel[]>(@"async () => {
    return window.dataLayer.map(
      data => ({
        Event : {
          name: data.event,
          creativeName: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.creative_name || null,
          creativeSlot: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.creative_slot || null,
          index: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.index || null,
          itemBrand: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.item_brand || null,
          itemId: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.item_id || null,
          itemListName: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.item_list_name || null,
          itemName: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.item_name || null,
          itemListLength: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.itemListLength || null,
          itemVariant: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.item_variant || null,
          locationId: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.location_id || null,
          pdCashbackRate: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.pd_cashback_rate || null,
          pdOfferEndDate: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.pd_offer_end_date || null,
          promotionId: data?.ecommerce_ga4?.items[0]?.promotion_id || null
        }
      })
    );
  }") ?? throw new Exception("DataLayer is empty");
}

public Task validateDataLayer(string dataLayerCheckType) {
  if (_dataLayer != null) {
    foreach (var data in _dataLayer) {
      if (data.Event != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Data: " + data.Event.name);
      }
    }
  }
}

[Theory]
[InlineData(DeviceType.Mobile)]
public async Task Category_Page_Should_Have_All_Heroes(DeviceType deviceType) {
  // Arrange
  var page = new CategoryPage(_fixture);
  await page.SetupPage(deviceType);

  // Act
  await page.GotoPage("/category/fashion/");

  // Assert
  await HasSuperHero();
} 

